# How to compile and run xv6 on windows?

Tags: unix, operating-system, emulation, xv6

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to compile and run xv6 on windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7534388/how-to-compile-and-run-xv6-on-windows)

We are being taught [xv6](http://pdos.csail.mit.edu/6.828/xv6/) in our course. Currently we use to login to linux server of our school using *putty* in windows.

There we make changes in source of xv6 (using vim), then compile and run it in *qemu* simply

```
make clean
make
make qemu-nox
```

It is not always possible to connect to their servers therefore I want to be able to compile and run xv6 withing windows (in some emulator obviously).

What emulator I can use for above kind work? (edit code, compile and run) and how?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to build the xv6 system using cygwin from www.cygwin.org; make sure you install gcc, make and a decent editor (emacs or vim or just use a regular windows editor like notepad++).  After that, you can run the resulting image with one of the qemu ports for windows; I found Qemu Manager to be quite easy to use (http://www.davereyn.co.uk/download.htm).  You will have to modify the Makefile to point to the proper qemu location.