# How to compile and run xv6 on windows?

Tags: windows, unix, compilation, virtual-machine, xv6

We are being taught [xv6](http://pdos.csail.mit.edu/6.828/xv6/) in our course. Currently we use to login to linux server of our school using *putty* in windows.

There we make changes in source of xv6 (using vim), then compile and run it in *qemu* simply

```
make clean
make
make qemu-nox
```

It is not always possible to connect to their servers therefore I want to be able to compile and run xv6 withing windows (in some emulator obviously).

What emulator I can use for above kind work? (edit code, compile and run) and how?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to compile and run xv6 on windows?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7531696/how-to-compile-and-run-xv6-on-windows)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, there are reasonable instructions on how to construct environment for building and using XV6 under Windows in the site http://www.cs.mta.ac.il/~carmi/Teaching/OS.xv6/index.html.
The emulator they are using for actually running it is Bochs.

Comment: The link is broken

Answer (score 6):

If you wanna use WSL (Windows sub-system for Linux) on **Windows 10**, this might help.

[Follow Instructions regarding Windows here](https://gcallah.github.io/OperatingSystems/xv6Install.html) **or**

**Step 1:** enable and setup WSL following [this](http://www.howtogeek.com/249966/how-to-install-and-use-the-linux-bash-shell-on-windows-10/).

**Step 2:** run WSL bash and install required stuffs on WSL.

- open CMD
- type `cd <xv6-source-path>`
- type `bash` and this will switch CMD into WSL bash
- then `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install git nasm build-essential qemu gdb`

**Step 3:** **disable video device** for qemu in **Makefile**.

- open Makefile in xv6 source directory with any text editor.
- find the line starting with

> QEMUOPTS =

- **append** `-display none` to this line and save the file.

**Step 4:** type linux like commands in that terminal i.e

- first `make`
- then `make qemu`

Now if everything is okay, you should be in the xv6 terminal

Answer (score 4):

You can run Linux inside [VirtualBox](http://ww.virtualbox.org), that would give you the same environment on your machine that you use on the school's server.  Then you could continue to run xv6 within qemu.  You'll need a reasonably capable machine for this, though -- a dual-core CPU with 4G of memory is the minimum I'd attempt this with.

Comment: I only have 1 GB Ram. That probably won't help because I'll be running an emulator (qemu), within an emulator (VirtualBox)

Comment: VirtualBox is not an emulator, it's a virtual machine. Big difference. Given how cheap RAM is these days, it might be worth upgrading the RAM in your laptop.

Answer (score 1):

I'd go for some sort VM solution (as suggested by TMN) as well, but it might be worth a try building it on Cygwin if you don't have the hardware to run a sufficiently specced VM.

Comment: I feel difficult to use Cygwin, after I install it, can I do all as I told in my question (make and run on qemu)?

Comment: Well, there is a version of qemu for windows, and you need gcc to build xv6. GCC is provided by Cygwin. Is it going to work? I don't know, but it's an option for you to try.

Answer (score 0):

I had tried the above but `make qemu-nox` gave me this error:

```
Cannot set up guest memory 'pc.ram': Cannot allocate memory
```

I opened up the Virtual Box GUI, right clicked on the VM, when it was turned off (on halt), I right-clicked on the VM, then clicked the "system" tab, and then changed the motherboard memory to over 2000MB.

After that I ran:

```
make
make qemu-nox
```

This worked for me even though nothing else worked.

Answer (score 0):

I have succeeded to build and run xv6 with Command Prompt (cmd.exe) on Windows 10. That's what I've done. Not on Linux, nor Windows10 + WSL environment, nor Windwos10 + Cygwin or MSYS environment, I built it on Windows10 using Command Prompt.
You need the following for Windows: MinGW, BusyBox, and QEMU. The xv6 source code modified by me can be download the following URL.

https://github.com/mirokuuno/xv6-windows

The details are documented in "How to build and run Unix-xv6 with Command Prompt on Windows" .